# c standard and bitshifts

Tags: c, standards, bit-shift

This question was first inspired by the (unexpected) results of this code:

```
uint16_t   t16 = 0;
uint8_t     t8 = 0x80;
uint8_t t8_res;

t16    = (t8 << 1);
t8_res = (t8 << 1);

printf("t16: %x\n", t16);    // Expect 0, get 0x100
printf(" t8: %x\n", t8_res); // Expect 0, get 0
```

But it turns out this makes sense:

**6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**

*Constraints*

***2** Each of the operands shall have integer type*

Thus the originally confused line is equivalent to:

```
t16 = (uint16_t) (((int) t8) << 1);
```

A little non-intuitive IMHO, but at least well-defined.

Ok, great, but then we do:

```
{
uint64_t t64 = 1;
t64 <<= 31;
printf("t64: %lx\n", t64); // Expect 0x80000000, get 0x80000000
t64 <<= 31;
printf("t64: %lx\n", t64); // Expect 0x0, get 0x4000000000000000
}
```

// edit: following the same literal argument as above, the following should be equivalent:

```
t64 = (uint64_t) (((int) t64) << 31);
```

// hence my confusion / expectation [end_edit]

Now, we get the intuitive result, but not what would be derived from my (literal) reading of the standard.  When / how does this "further automatic type promotion" take place? Or is there a limitation elsewhere that a type can never be demoted (that would make sense?), in that case, how do the promotion rules apply for:

```
uint32_t << uint64_t
```

Since the standard does say both arguments are promoted to int; should both arguments be promoted to the same type here?

// edit:

More specifically, what should the result of:

```
uint32_t t32 = 1;
uint64_t t64_one = 1;
uint64_t t64_res;

t64_res = t32 << t64_one;
```

// end edit

The answer to the above question is resolved when we recognize that the spec does not demand a promotion to `int` specifically, rather to an `integer type`, which uint64_t qualifies as.

// CLARIFICATION EDIT:

Ok, but now I am confused again.  Specifically, if `uint8_t` is an integer type, then why is it being promoted to `int` at all? It does not seem to be related to the constant int 1, as the following exercise demonstrates:

```
{
uint16_t t16 = 0;
uint8_t t8 = 0x80;
uint8_t t8_one = 1;
uint8_t t8_res;

t16 = (t8 << t8_one);
t8_res = (t8 << t8_one);

printf("t16: %x\n", t16);
printf(" t8: %x\n", t8_res);
}

t16: 100
 t8: 0
```

Why is the (t8 << t8_one) expression being promoted if uint8_t is an integer type?

--

For reference, I'm working from ISO/IEC 9899:TC9, WG14/N1124 May 6, 2005.  If that's out of date and someone could also provide a link to a more recent copy, that'd be appreciated as well.

Comment: I can't quite understand why you say `// Expect 0x0` after that second shift left by 31 bits...

Comment: I am confused as Greg is, but would expect that types are never automatically demoted (narrowed), only promoted (widened).

Comment: By my reading of the standard, t64 = (uint64_t) (((int) t64) << 31) is an equivalent line, in which case the set bit should be lost to int truncation.

Comment: N1124 consists of the C99 standard with the first two Technical Corrigenda merged into it.  [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is the same, but with all three TCs.  (There are no major differences.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constraint in §6.5.7 that *"Each of the operands shall have integer type."* is a constraint that means you cannot use the bitwise shift operators on non-integer types like floating point values or pointers.  It does not cause the effect you are noting.

The part that *does* cause the effect is in the next paragraph:

> 3. The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

The *integer promotions* are described in §6.3.1.1:

> 2. The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int`
>   or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and
>     `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value
>   is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned
>   int`. These are called the *integer promotions*. All other types are
>   unchanged by the integer promotions.

`uint8_t` has a lesser rank than `int`, so the value is converted to an `int` (since we know that an `int` must be able to represent all the values of `uint8_t`, given the requirements on the ranges of those two types).

The ranking rules are complex, but they guarantee that a type with a higher rank cannot have a lesser precision.  This means, in effect, that types cannot be "demoted" to a type with lesser precision by the integer promotions (it is possible for `uint64_t` to be promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`, but *only* if the range of the type is at least that of `uint64_t`).

In the case of `uint32_t << uint64_t`, the rule that kicks in is *"The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand"*.  So we have a few possibilities:

- If `int` is at least 33 bits, then `uint32_t` will be promoted to `int` and the result will be `int`;
- If `int` is less than 33 bits and `unsigned int` is at least 32 bits, then `uint32_t` will be promoted to `unsigned int` and the result will be `unsigned int`;
- If `unsigned int` is less than 32 bits then `uint32_t` will be unchanged and the result will be `uint32_t`.

On today's common desktop and server implementations, `int` and `unsigned int` are usually 32 bits, and so the second possibility will occur (`uint32_t` is promoted to `unsigned int`).  In the past it was common for `int` / `unsigned int` to be 16 bits, and the third possibility would occur (`uint32_t` left unpromoted).

The result of your example:

```
uint32_t t32 = 1;
uint64_t t64_one = 1;
uint64_t t64_res;

t64_res = t32 << t64_one;
```

Will be the value `2` stored into `t64_res`.  Note though that this is not affected by the fact that the result of the expression is not `uint64_t` - and example of an expression that *would* be affected is:

```
uint32_t t32 = 0xFF000;
uint64_t t64_shift = 16;
uint64_t t64_res;

t64_res = t32 << t64_shift;
```

The result here is `0xf0000000`.

Note that although the details are fairly intricate, you can boil it all down to a fairly simple rule that you should keep in mind:

> In C, arithmetic is never done in types narrower than `int` /
>   `unsigned int`.

Comment: Ah.... that last bit in §6.3.1.1 sec 2 really sealed it for me.  As well as your final summary rule. My mental model of C had been much more of 'promote on demand' (hence the uint8_t questions tacked on the end).  This answer makes a lot of sense, thank you for your time.

-pat

Answer (score 8):

I think the source of your confusion might be that the following two statements are *not* equivalent:

- Each of the operands shall have integer type
- Each of the operands shall have `int` type

`uint64_t` is an integer type.

Comment: Indeed, this is the source of OP's confusion.

Comment: @Pat: Note that `uint8_t` is an integer type also, so this rule isn't responsible for the behaviour you see in your first example.  As [Jens Gustedt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947982/c-standard-and-bitshifts/7948145#7948145) says, it's the "usual arithmetic conversions" that cause values whose types are narrower than `int` to be promoted (to either `int` or `unsigned`).

Comment: @caf having read the comment from Jens I have further revised the question. Any further insight?

Answer (score 3):

You found the wrong rule in the standard :( The relevant is something like "the usual integer type promotions apply". This is what hits you for the first example. If an integer type like `uint8_t` has a rank that is smaller than `int` it is promoted to `int`. `uint64_t` has not a rank that is smaller than `int` or `unsigned` so no promotion is performed and the `<<` operator is applied to the `uint64_t` variable.

*Edit:* All integer types smaller than `int` are promoted for arithmetic. This is just a fact of life :) Whether or not `uint32_t` is promoted depends on the platform, because it might have the same rank or higher than `int` (not promoted) or a smaller rank (promoted).

Concerning the `<<` operator the type of the right operand is not really important, what counts for the number of bits is the left one (with the above rules). More important for the right one is its value. It musn't be negative or exceed the width of the (promoted) left operand.

Comment: Edited main question since line breaks are not allowed in comments, please take a look?