# printf prints big number for uint_8

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  uint8_t ui8 = 0xff;
  printf(" %x\n", ui8);
  printf(" %x\n", (uint8_t)24);
  printf(" %x\n", ui8 << (uint8_t)24);
}
```

The output is :

```
 ff
 18
 ff000000
```

The question is: If I have two `uint8_t` variables why the result is "promoted" to a higher rank. If it is not promoted, why do I get such a big number. I test it no MinGW win7-64bit platform

Comment: `printf(" %x\n", (uint8_t)(ui8 << 24));` -- and the value of type `uint8_t` is still going to be converted (to `int`) anyway.

Comment: Why do you want to shift an 8-bit variable 24 steps?

Comment: @klutt
To compose 32-bit value from 4 byte (serial communication) data buffer. Kind of parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Both* arguments of `<<` are converted to `int` prior to the evaluation, *despite* the fact that you've attempted to force the issue with `(uint8_t)24`.

This is necessarily true since `uint8_t` is narrower than an `int` on any platform.

So the result, `ff000000`, you observe is consistent with an `int` being at least 32 bits wide on your platform.

Comment: Where did you get this rule from?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947982/c-standard-and-bitshifts

Comment: Wow, that was subtle.

Comment: @Hairi: Yes, it's one for the pub quiz, for certain.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is something called [*usual arithmetic conversion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) which leads to [*integer promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) for both arguments of the `<<` operator.

If you instead of using the shift expression directly in the `printf` argument, and instead stored it in a `uint8_t` variable, then the result would be zero. *However* when you call `printf` you would instead have a [*default argument promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) which would turn the `uint8_t` variable into an `int`. But that would lead to another problem because even though the format `"%x"` expects an `int` (an `unsigned int` actually, see e.g. [this `printf` and family reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)) the data is actually an `uint8_t`. That means you have mismatched format specifier and argument, leading to *undefined behavior*. The correct format specifier to print an `uint8_t` is `"%hhx"`, or better yet use the `PRI8x` macro:

```
uint8_t result = ...
printf("%" PRI8x "\n", result);
```

See e.g. [this format macro reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants).

Comment: But I see this: "If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.".
Then how come they are still converted to int?

Comment: @Hairi Where do you see that? None of my links say that.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe

Bullet #1

Comment: @Hairi That answer is missing a little bit of preamble, namely a section saying "Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both  operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands", where the "following rules" is the list you read. That means the integer promotion is done *first* and *then* if the types are the same no more conversions are made.